# How can I use realloc function without discarding the old memories

Tags: c

First of all, I'm sorry for my bad English.

I have a question about 'realloc' function in language C.
I thought it allocates memories with given length.
When the memories ain't enough for the given length, it copies whole memories to another memory pointer and returns it.

I wanted to use realloc function with preserving the old memories.
So I sentenced another pointer and made it pointing at the old memories.
But whenever 'realloc' function works, it frees the old memories.
How can I preserve old memories?
In addition, I want to know why this is happenend.

the below is code and its result I've used for testing realloc function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* ptr1, lenPtr1;
int* ptr2;

void double_ptr1(){
    lenPtr1 *= 2;
    ptr1 = (int*)realloc(ptr1, sizeof(int) * lenPtr1);
}

void print(){
    printf("ptr1 -> %p, *ptr1 = %d\n", ptr1, *ptr1);
    printf("ptr2 -> %p, *ptr2 = %d\n", ptr2, *ptr2);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    lenPtr1 = 10;
    ptr1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * lenPtr1);
    ptr2 = ptr1;
    *ptr1 = 10;

    print();
    double_ptr1();
    print();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

ptr1 -> 0108D2F0, *ptr1 = 10
ptr2 -> 0108D2F0, *ptr2 = 10

ptr1 -> 00FF5740, *ptr1 = 10
ptr2 -> 0108D2F0, *ptr2 = -17891602

Comment: realloc allocates new memory, copies the contents of the old memory and then frees the old memory.  So it really does reallocate the memory.  If you want to copy the memory into a larger space then use malloc and memcpy.

Comment: Simply allocate a new larger block of memory and `memcpy()` the old to new -- which will not effect the old block in any way. @JerryJeremiah - you beat me by a minute `:)` In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: and please avoid global variables

Comment: I think we should mention that `realloc` does not _always_ create a new [larger] area and copy into it. First, it looks to see if the current area has some free space abutting it, and if it's large enough to contain the new, combined, larger length, and the policy for the given memory arena allows the increase, it will remove the new space from the free pool [and adjust subarea pointers accordingly]. Likewise, for areas that are _shrinking_ it _may_ just add the reclaimed space to the free pool. Or, it may alloc a new area [from a "smaller" arena], do the copy, and free the old area.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah So if I want to preserve the old memory, I shouldn't use realloc function. thanks for your kind comment. It helps me a lot.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've read the post you mentioned. I'm not sure I understand it, so I should study more. But it's really helpful. Thanks for that. :)

Comment: @phuclv I've never thought about global variables before you mentioned that. I searched why I should avoid using global variables and I think it's really helpful. Thanks for mentioning that. :)

Comment: @송민기 - I added an answer explaining.

Comment: @CraigEstey I should study about free pool first. Thanks for your kind comment. :)

Comment: @CraigEstey in the abstract machine (which is how C is defined) it always allocates a new block. This can be optimized by an implementation placing the new block at the same physical address as the old, although there is no way (in a conforming program) to detect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example incorporating all improvements suggested in the comments and avoiding the use of global variables, and freeing all allocated memory before the program exits. There is only a need to hold the terminal window open on windows, so conditionally enclose the `system("pause");`.

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *double_ptr (int *ptr, int *ptrsz)      /* pass needed information as parameters */
{
    int *newptr = malloc (2 * *ptrsz * sizeof *newptr); /* allocate new block of mem */
    
    if (newptr) {                                       /* validate allocation */
        memcpy (newptr, ptr, *ptrsz * sizeof *ptr);     /* copy to new block of mem */
        *ptrsz *= 2;                                    /* update allocated size */
    }
    
    return newptr;      /* return pointer */
}

void print (int *ptr1, int *ptr2)           /* pass needed information as parameters */
{
    /* only one call to printf required */
    printf ("ptr1 -> %p, *ptr1 = %d\nptr2 -> %p, *ptr2 = %d\n\n",
            (void*)ptr1, *ptr1, (void*)ptr2, *ptr2);
}

int main (void) {
    
    int *ptr1 = NULL, *ptr2 = NULL, lenPtr1 = 10;       /* avoid global variables */

    if (!(ptr1 = malloc (lenPtr1 * sizeof *ptr1))) {    /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-ptr");
        return 1;
    }
    ptr2 = ptr1;    /* pointer 1 and 2 hold same address where 10 is stored in memory */
    *ptr1 = 10;

    printf ("lenPtr1: %d\n", lenPtr1);                  /* output len, addresses, values */
    print (ptr1, ptr2);
    
    if (!(ptr1 = double_ptr (ptr1, &lenPtr1))) {        /* double size of ptr1 */
        perror ("malloc-double-ptr1");
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf ("lenPtr1: %d\n", lenPtr1);                  /* output len, addresses, values */
    print (ptr1, ptr2);
    
    free (ptr1);                                        /* free allcoated memory */
    free (ptr2);
    
#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)
    system("pause");
#endif
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/doubleptrsz
lenPtr1: 10
ptr1 -> 0xb18260, *ptr1 = 10
ptr2 -> 0xb18260, *ptr2 = 10

lenPtr1: 20
ptr1 -> 0xb186a0, *ptr1 = 10
ptr2 -> 0xb18260, *ptr2 = 10
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I want to express how much I thank to you, but my English isn't good enough to do that. Thanks to you, I learned not only realloc but also how to code properly. :)

Comment: Aside: `sizeof *newptr * 2 * *ptrsz` has an advantage over `2 * *ptrsz * sizeof *newptr`.  The first uses `size_t` math throughout that less likely overflows the `int` math of `2 * *ptrsz`.

Comment: Yes, thank you chux, that was a conscious decision to let the `int`, `size_t` issue slide. Since we were dealing with values from 10 - 20 (and had covered quite a bit), that was omitted. But a note here is warranted. The type for `lenPtr1` should ideally be type `size_t` and not type `int`. (you can't have a negative allocation size) Additionally, all allocation functions `malloc()`, `callod()` and `realloc()` expect `size_t` as the type for the size value. It will not change anything in this example, but using `size_t` is proper.

Answer (score 1):

When you realloc the original pointer, which is pointed by ptr2, the address of the original pointer is removed.

So after you realloc the ptr1, ptr2 points address that does not exists anymore.

If you want to preserve old memory, then you just need to malloc(or calloc) new memory to ptr1 with no realloc original one.

Answer (score 1):

> *When the memories ain't enough for the given length, it copies whole memories to another memory pointer and returns it.*

Not quite. `realloc` ***always*** deallocates the old memory. It *may* return the same pointer.

From C11 7.20.3.4 `realloc`...

> The realloc function deallocates  the  old  object  pointed  to  by `ptr` and  returns  a pointer  to  a  new  object  that  has  the  size  specified  by `size`.... The realloc function  returns  a  pointer  to  the  new object  (which  may  have  the  same value  as  a  pointer  to  the  old  object)

---

> *I wanted to use realloc function with preserving the old memories.*

You can't.

If you need more memory, `malloc` a new hunk of memory instead of reallocing the old one.

If you want to shrink memory, continue to use the memory as is. It'll work fine, it's just a waste of memory.

I'd recommend neither. Instead, redesign whatever you're doing so the pointer is accessed indirectly. Perhaps using [a pointer to a pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#Multiple_indirection). Or put the pointer inside a struct and pass around a pointer to the struct.

Alternatively, redesign it so you do not need to realloc. For example, when reading from a file use a fixed size buffer to read the line and then copy that to memory with exactly enough space.

```
// A large buffer to reuse for each line.
char buf[BUFSIZ];

while( fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) ) {
  // Allocate exactly enough space for the line.
  // In reality, use strdup.
  char *string = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1);
  strcpy(string, buf);
}
```

Or change to a data structure which does not rely on a single block of memory. For example, a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) instead of an array.

---

> *In addition, I want to know why this is happened.*

[There are many implementations of malloc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Implementations), but they all must allocate contiguous blocks of memory with no overlap.

Consider two calls to `malloc`.

```
char *foo = malloc(8);
char *bar = malloc(8);
```

And let's say foo and bar are allocated adjacent blocks of memory like so. (Note: there's no guarantee they will be adjacent and many reasons why they shouldn't be.)

```
0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
^^^^^^^^
|       ^^^^^^^^
foo     |
        bar
```

Now you try to grow foo.

```
foo = realloc(foo, 16);
```

If realloc tries to keep the same pointer, foo would have to overlap into bar's memory.

```
0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|       ^^^^^^^^
foo     |
        bar
```

That's not allowed, allocations cannot overlap. They also must be contiguous, so it cannot do this:

```
0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^
|       ^^^^^^^^
foo     |
        bar
```

If it were allowed to do that, pointer math would not work. You would not be able to reliably add to foo to walk through its allocated memory.

So realloc must free foo and allocate a new block. (Again, no guarantee where it will be allocated.)

```
0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
        ^^^^^^^^
        |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        bar     |
                foo
```

Comment: I have one more question. You said you wouldn't recommend to use ```malloc``` to preserve the old memory. Can I ask why?

Comment: @송민기 *In general*, because it requires you to duplicate the content of the old memory which is a waste of memory. A design which requires you to hang onto a specific pointer location is inflexible. Again, in general.

Comment: @송민기 For example, your problem stems from using global variables. It is better to not use globals, as in David C. Raskin's answer than to duplicate the memory.